# VSS History - Exclude Labels

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, history

Within the GUI of VSS it is possible to view the history of an item 'including' or 'excluding' the labels.

I'm trying to do the same thing but from the command line but I just can't see which switch I need to use in order to 'exclude' labels (by default they are included).

e.g. I'm running:- ss.exe HISTORY -I- $/Source/Path/FileName.txt

Why? We have Cruise Control setup to automatically create a label on each successful build...so there are alot of labels. When I run that 'get history' command above it takes 20-30 secs per file and I want to run a process that will hit every file...

If anyone can tell me which switch I need to use (it must be there if the GUI allows you to choose??) that would help very much :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the -L parameter as follows:
ss.exe history -L   : shows history labels only
ss.exe history -L-  : shows history without labels